# Prove that $f$ has finite number of roots

Tags: real-analysis, functions, roots

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. If there do not exist any $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)=0$, prove that $f$ has only finite number of zeros in $[0,1]$.

I'm not getting any idea how to proceed.

Comment: Suppose $f$ has infinitely many zeros in $[0,\, 1]$. Show that then you must have an $x \in [0,\,1]$ with $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: The point here is that a zero of a $C^1$ function is isolated if the derivative does not vanish there.

Comment: Actually that is not necessary (think of $x^2$). I guess the statement could be even weakened as "there are only finite such points".

Comment: You need to pass information back and forth between the function and the derivative. For this you know, Lagrange's theorem, or some of its particular cases, like Rolle. Assume infinitely many zeros, and look at a cluster point in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Also, you need to take into account, that there is something special about the domain of $f$. (For instance, it does not work with $\mathbb R$, the sine function is a counterexample)

Comment: @DavidMitra You don't need that result, as $f(x)=0$ by continuity and $$f'(x)=\lim_{t \to x} \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=\lim_{n} \frac{f(x_n)-f(x)}{x_n-x}$$

Comment: @N.S. Of course... (deleting..)

Comment: @DanielFischer How can i do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combining the comments:

Assume by contradiction that $f$ has infinitely many zeroes in $[0,1]$. Then, we can find a sequence $x_n$ so that $f(x_n)=0$.

As $[0,1]$ is compact, $x_n$ has a converging subsequence. Lets call this subsequence $y_n$ and let $y=\lim_n y_n$.

Then by continuity $f(y)=0$ and $f'(y) =\lim_{x \to y} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(y_n)-f(y)}{y_n-y}=0$ contradiction.

Comment: In case you'll see this, could you explain why $f'(y)=0$? I only see a fraction whose numerator and denominator both go to $0$.

Comment: @KitKat The numerator IS zero.

Answer (score 8):

The OP's last comment indicates that he may still be clueless, so here is a more explicit suggestion. First use the Taylor formula $f(x)=f(x_0)+ f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + o(x-x_0)$ to show that zeros with nonvanishing derivative must be isolated. This means that there is an open interval containing $x_0$ with no other zeros in it.  Taking such an interval for each zero, we get an open cover of the set of zeros.  Now use the compactness of the set of zeros of $f$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I see somebody is unhappy about this answer. Why? If it is too explicit as per SE guidelines, I will delete it.