# Finite roots of $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ derivable such that not exists $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

My doubt is about the problem who has already asked here several times:

> Let $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. If there do not exist any $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = f′(x) = 0$, prove that f  has only finite number of zeros in [0,1].

In this question: [Prove that $f$ has finite number of roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445097/prove-that-f-has-finite-number-of-roots), the second answer suggests that:

> First use the Taylor formula $f(x)=f(x_0)+f′(x_0)(x−x_0)+o(x−x_0)$ to show that zeros with nonvanishing derivative must be isolated.

This was not clear to me. I would like to check my demonstration and point out possible errors.

**My proof:** Suppose that the set

$$Z = \{x \in [0,1] ; f(x) = 0\}$$

is infinite. Let us now suppose that $Z$ is not discrete. Then there exists $x_0 \in Z \cap Z'$. Then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have that

$$[(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon) - x_0] \cap Z \ne \emptyset.$$

Let $h \ne 0$ such that $x_0 + h \in [0,1]$. Consider then formula of taylor

\begin{align*}
f(x_0 + h) & \ = \ f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h + r(h)\\
& \ = \ f'(x_0) + r(h)\\
& \ = \ \bigg[f'(x_0) + \dfrac{r(h)}{h}\bigg]h
\end{align*}

Since $x_0$ is an accumulation point, if we take $\varepsilon$ small enough, we will find $h'$ small enough such that $f(x_0 + h') \in Z$. But this must be absurd because for $h'$ sufficiently small we will have to

\begin{align*}
f(x_0 + h') & \ = \ \bigg[\underbrace{f'(x_0)}_{\ne 0} + \underbrace{\dfrac{r(h)}{h}}_{= 0}\bigg]\underbrace{h}_{\ne 0}\\
& \ \ne \ 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your $x_0$ is in $Z \cap Z'$ ($Z'$ is undefined but I know what you meant), right? So why is $f'(x_0)$ equal to $0$ at the end?

Comment: @BrunoB $f'(x_0) \ne 0$.

Comment: I meant "why is it not equal to $0$?" sorry. I thought the $Z'$ you introduced was implicitly meant to be $Z$ but for $f'$?

Comment: Z' is the set of accumulation points of $Z$. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I see, I've never seen that notation before...

Comment: This notation is common in Brazilian book's of real analysis. Did you notice anything wrong with my proof?